# Reduce following expression to one literal, boolean algebra

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

$$W'X(Z'+Y'Z)+X(W+W'YZ)$$

The goal is to reduce the following to **one literal**
So after I expanded it out, i got the following:
$$W'XZ'+W'XY'Z+WX+W'XYZ$$

Now from here, I got stuck and didn't know what to do next. So i went and checked the solutions and it gave me
$$W'XZ'+W'XZ+WX$$
$$W'X+WX$$
$$X$$

Now I'm just wondering , how the last term in the equation suddenly dissapeared and I was guessing it was the **consensus theorem** which is something like:
$$XY+X'Z+YZ = XY+X'Z$$

But I am confused because I don't know **when** and **what** form the equation has to be in order for me to able to use that theorem.
If someone could show me the algebraic process to get rid of the last terms, it would be great (for my question, not for the theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We essentially use only the distributive rule

- $AB + AC = A(B+C)$ or $BA + CA = (B+C)A$ and
- the identity that for any $A$, $(A + A') = 1$.

Starting from where you left off:

$$
\begin{align}
W'XZ'+W'XY'Z+WX+W'XYZ
& = W'XZ' + W'XZ(Y' + Y) + WX \\ \\
& = W'XZ' + W'XZ(1) + WX \\ \\
& = W'XZ' + W'XZ + WX \\ \\
& = W'X(Z'+Z)  + WX \\ \\
& = W'X(1) + WX \\ \\
& = W'X + WX \\ \\
& = (W' + W)X \\ \\
& = (1)X \\ \\
& = X
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, can you explain your very first step? I don't see how you manipulated it. Also I think you missed a W. How did the last term dissapear?

Comment: The first step uses the distributive rule: The common factor of the second and fourth term is $W'XZ$. So by the distributive rule $W'X\color{blue}{\bf Y'}Z + W'X\color{blue}{\bf Y}Z = W'XZ(\color{blue}{\bf Y' + Y})$

Comment: Oh damn I missed that..

Comment: I thought it was more complicated than it actually is

Comment: Not a problem! It sometimes gets confusing with all the LETTERS, their ordering, and keeping straight which letters are negated...We all have our days :-)